# Checking Word Grids

Tags: code-golf

**Your Task**

Given a list of words, check if they form a valid word grid. They form a valid grid if there are **N** words with **N** letters and they spell the same words vertically as they do horizontally. The words can be given in any order. `[FILE, ICED, LEAD, EDDY]` = `True` and `[FILE, LEAD, EDDY, ICED]` = `True`. Print `True` if it is valid or `False` if it is not

**Here's some more examples**

```
F I L E
I C E D
L E A D
E D D Y

O G R E        
G A I A       
R I G S        
E A S Y        

C A M P
A X E L
M E M O
P L O W

S P A S M
P A S T A
A S P E N
S T E E L
M A N L Y
```

This is code golf so lowest bytes wins

Comment: So we have to check all permutations of the input right?

Comment: @Maltysen Correct. Permutations of the words not the letters in the words

Comment: Any truthy/falsy values are fine, or the exact strings "True" and "False" ?

Comment: You just have to check that the grid (in some permutation) is symmetric, not that the words are valid according to some dictionary?

Comment: @xnor That's correct. The input can be gibberish but it has to be symmetrical gibberish

Comment: @Optimizer You have to print the words `True` and `False`

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted?

Comment: @SirParselot Probably because they find the challenge is fairly trivial / uninteresting.

Comment: @SirParselot I might also guess someone is unhappy their language has to convert to `True`/`False` while others have them natively.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth - <strike>10</strike> 9 bytes

The actual check is very easy, in just three bytes with `CIQ`. The permutation part takes the other 6.

```
.EmCId.pQ
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.EmCId.pQ&input=%5B%22FILE%22%2C+%22LEAD%22%2C+%22EDDY%22%2C+%22ICED%22%5D&debug=1).

It `m`aps over the `.p`ermutations of the (`Q`) input, each time checking if the loop var(`d`) is `I`nvarient under (`C`) rotation. Then it checks if `.E`any are true.

Answer (score 5):

### CJam (<strike>25</strike> 24 bytes)

```
q~e!{_z=},"True""False"?
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~e!%7B_z%3D%7D%2C%22True%22%22False%22%3F&input=%5B%22FILE%22%20%22LEAD%22%20%22EDDY%22%20%22ICED%22%5D). Pretty trivial apart from the specified output, because CJam doesn't have a Boolean type.

With thanks to [Sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21487/sp3000) for saving one stroke.

Comment: @Sp3000, true. I'm so used to expecting the interleaved string approach to be shorter that I didn't even try the naïve approach.

Comment: Has Peter abandoned GolfScript in favor of CJam??

Comment: @AlexA., not entirely. But for this question, GS can't possibly get anywhere near CJam. `e!` would require writing a recursive function in GS: that's 6 characters before it even does anything.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 114 bytes

Did somebody say "super long solution"?? It just so happens that I have one for you.

```matlab
a->(L=length(a);P(x)=reshape(split(join(x),""),L,L);print(any([P(p)==P(p)'for p=permutations(a)])?"True":"False"))
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an array and prints to stdout. It works by generating all permutations, turning the arrays into matrices of letters and checking whether each matrix is equal to its transpose. Unfortunately booleans are lowercase in Julia, otherwise I wouldn't have had to do the ternary.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 51 bytes

```
import Data.List
any((==)=<<transpose).permutations
```

Usage example: `any((==)=<<transpose).permutations $ ["LEAD","FILE","ICED","EDDY"]` -> `True`.

How it works: check if any of the permutations equals it's transposition. Luckily Haskell's native boolean values are `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>87</s> 85 Bytes

Straightforward solution using `zip()` to transpose.

*Saved two bytes on both thanks to xnor.*

```py
from itertools import*
print any(zip(*c)==map(tuple,c)for c in permutations(input()))
```

**Solution without relying on imports, <s>139</s> <s>138</s> 136 Bytes**

```py
p=lambda l:[[j]+k for i,j in enumerate(l)for k in p(l[:i]+l[-~i:])]if~-len(l)else[l]
print any(zip(*c)==map(tuple,c)for c in p(input()))
```

<sup>If there's a way to get around using enumerate, let me know! :)</sup>

Input for both should be formatted like so:

```py
["FILE","ICED","EDDY","LEAD"]
```

---

<sup><sup>Psst. Hey! Here's a solution in Symbolic, something I'm working on.
`Ƥ(Ʌ(ʐ(*c)==ϻ(ϰ,c)ϝcϊƥ(Ί)))`</sup></sup>

Comment: You can do `any()` for `sum()>0`.

Comment: are you submitting this for the bounty?

Comment: @Maltysen No, I just did it because I was experimenting :)

Comment: Symbolic looks really cool! But fyi, the 31 characters in that solution make for a score of _41_ bytes in UTF-8. It may not be the most competitive golfing language. ;)

Comment: @AlexA. I don't think I could make anything on the level of Pyth/CJam/GolfScript, I'm just doing it for fun ;P

Comment: Well like I said, it looks really cool. I'm excited to see it develop!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 74

```
s=input().split()
print all(''.join(s)[s.index(w)::len(w)]in s for w in s)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
p⟨\=≡⟩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v@DR/BUxto86Fz6av/L//@hoJV8lHSVHIPYDYh8gjlSK1YlWCgayAqAyILYvXDQEiF2h2AcsiqwuBMwGicJEAqBq/ZRiYwE)

Assuming output can be "true." and "false." instead of "True" and "False".

If not, it's a trivial change to:

#### 22 bytes

```
p⟨\=≡⟩∧"True"|∧"False"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv@DR/BUxto86Fz6av/JRx3KlkKLSVKUaEMstMac4Ven//2iF6GglVyUdJRcojlSK1YlWcgOyPIHYB4hdwSIgnjOYB1IHEvGB8hwhIrE6IKP8gRx3IA6Ca3SHKvEE0yCRICgPJBMMFoEZEwxxAMQoX6igH9QdEJeBlAQgKfeFi4ZA3eMKVg8SRVYXArceJhIAVesHsxBokQLIAwpAxSARkB4FkGsVlEIhAu5wAZCHFWIB)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica (<strike>48</strike> 42 bytes)

```
Or@@(#==#&/@Characters@Permutations@#)&
```

Luckily `Transpose` can be represented by a single unicode character.

Comment:  is this the character for transpose? I found a different one on wolfram's website

Comment: [Yes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Transpose.html), U+F3C7. But it actually doesn't render correctly on my system. Copy&Pasting the code however works fine.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>90</s> 58 bytes

```
s=>s.every((l,i)=>s.map(p=>p[i]).join``==l)?'True':'False'
```

Old answer:

```
s=>~(n=s.split`
`).map((l,i)=>n.map(p=>p[i*2]).join` `==l).indexOf(!1)?'False':'True'
```

The newline is significant and counts as a byte.

---

ES5 Demo:

```js
function t(s) {
    return ~(n=s.split('\n')).map(function(l,i){return n.map(function(p){return o=p[i*2]}).join(' ')==l}).indexOf(!1)?'False':'True'
}

// Demo
document.getElementById('go').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = t(document.getElementById('input').value)
};
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif">Word Grids Snippet</h2><div><div  style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><textarea placeholder="Text here..." style="resize:none;width:70px;height:70px;border:1px solid #DDD;" id="input"></textarea><button id='go'>Run!</button></div><br><div style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><span style="font-family:sans-serif;">Output:</span><br><pre id="output" style="background-color:#DEDEDE;padding:1em;border-radius:2px;overflow-x:auto;"></pre></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Note: The code snippet will only return true if there is a single space between each letter in the code grid, as in the OP examples.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 97 bytes

91 bytes if we remove `.chomp` inside `map`

```
a=gets.chomp.split','.map{|_|_.chomp.chars};p a.permutation.map{|p|p[0].zip(*p[1..-1])===p}.any?
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB - <s>75</s> 98 bytes

*Note:* I didn't see that you had to output `True` or `False`, so I had to create an additional cell array that stores these two choices then we choose from this array when we're done.

---

This is a rather brute-force solution.  This assumes that you have loaded `A` in as a character matrix and that `A` is symmetric in size (i.e. # of rows is equal to # of columns):

```
c={'False','True'};o=0;for k=perms(1:size(A,1))'o=o|sum(sum(A(k,:)==A(k,:)'))==numel(A);end,c{o+1}
```

The overall process is to first create a 2D array of all possible permutations that goes from 1 up to as many words as we have `N`.  Each row of this matrix gives you a permutation enumerated from 1 up to `N`, and we can check either the number of rows or columns for the value `N`.  Next, we go through every possible permutation and rearrange the matrix `A`'s rows based on the permutation vector produced by that permutation.  For example, if `N=4`, and if we had `[1,4,2,3]` as  the permutation vector, it would rearrange the matrix `A` so that row 1 of the original matrix `A` appears first, followed by row 4 of the original matrix `A` appearing second, row 2 of the original matrix `A` appearing third and finally row 3 of the original matrix `A` appearing last.

The above problem is essentially checking to see that if we all of these matrix rearrangements for `A` over all possible permutations, we check to see if this rearranged matrix is equal to its transpose.  In order to facilitate this, I do an element-by-element equality check of the characters, and sum over this result.  If the sum is equal to the total size of the matrix, then we have a true result.  This code **will check** all possible permutations, even if we have found a match before we exhaust all possibilities.  The statement `o=0` is an indicator variable `o` that tells us whether we have found the condition being true or false.

Inside the loop, we keep updating `o` and checking for the above summation condition by logical ORing with the current result and with the current rearranged matrix condition.  It will be set to `true` if we have found such a condition or it gets to 1, and will stay `false` if we don't, or stays at 0.

### Minor Note

The `for` loop behaviour is rather undocumented, but if you specify a **matrix** to be what is iterating over the `for` loop, each value `k` would be a **column** of the said matrix.  For example, if we did:

```
B = [0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2; 3 3 3 3];
for k = B
    disp(k);
end
```

We would select out the first column of `B`, display it, then the next column of `B`, display it, etc... so you would get a series of `[0,1,2,3]'`s.

---

## Example Runs

```
>> A = ['FILE'; 'ICED'; 'LEAD'; 'EDDY'];
>> c={'False','True'};o=0;for k=perms(1:size(A,1))'o=o|sum(sum(A(k,:)==A(k,:)'))==numel(A);end,c{o+1}

ans =

    True

>> A = ['FILE'; 'LEAD'; 'EDDY'; 'ICED'];
>> c={'False','True'};o=0;for k=perms(1:size(A,1))'o=o|sum(sum(A(k,:)==A(k,:)'))==numel(A);end,c{o+1}

ans =

    True

>> A = ['OGRE'; 'GAIA'; 'RIGS'; 'EASY'];
>> c={'False','True'};o=0;for k=perms(1:size(A,1))'o=o|sum(sum(A(k,:)==A(k,:)'))==numel(A);end,c{o+1}

ans =

    True

>> A = ['CAMP', 'AXEL', 'MEMO', 'PLOW'];
>> c={'False','True'};o=0;for k=perms(1:size(A,1))'o=o|sum(sum(A(k,:)==A(k,:)'))==numel(A);end,c{o+1}

ans =

    True

>> A = ['SPASM', 'PASTA', 'ASPEN', 'STEEL', 'MANLY'];
>> c={'False','True'};o=0;for k=perms(1:size(A,1))'o=o|sum(sum(A(k,:)==A(k,:)'))==numel(A);end,c{o+1}

ans =

    True
```

---

Just to be sure, here's an example of where it shouldn't work:

```
>> A = ['CBMP'; 'APEL'; 'MCTO'; 'DLOX'];
>> A

A =

CBMP
APEL
MCTO
DLOX

>> c={'False','True'};o=0;for k=perms(1:size(A,1))'o=o|sum(sum(A(k,:)==A(k,:)'))==numel(A);end,c{o+1}

ans =

    False
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
øQi”‰¦”ë”žä
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I7AzEcNcx81bDi0DEgfXg0kju47vOT//2h1N08fV3UddU9nVxcg5ePqCKJcXVwi1WMB)

**Explanation:**

```python
ø        # Zip the (implicit) input, swapping columns and rows
 Q       # Check if it is equal to the (implicit) input
         # That's it, we're done.. If it weren't for the requirement of explicitly 
         # outputting the strings "True"/"False" instead of a truthy/falsey result..

i        # If the result is 1 (truthy):
 ”‰¦”    #  Output "True"
ë        # Else:
 ”žä     #  Output "False"
```

[See here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”‰¦”` is `True` and `”žä` is `False`.

---

**11 bytes alternative:**

```python
øQ”žä‰¦”#sè
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8I7ARw1zj@47vORRw4ZDy4Bs5eLDK/7/j1Z38/RxVddR93R2dQFSPq6OIMrVxSVSPRYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 134 bytes

```java
a->{int b=a.length,i=0,j=0;for(;i++<b;){for(;j<b;j++){if(a[j].length()!=b||a[i].charAt(j)!=a[j].charAt(i))return false;}}return true;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tU/BboJAFLz7Fa@cdoMS75Qmm0oTEySmeGmMhwcuuhQXsyw2DfLt9Gmwp5r04ml29s17M1PgCSfVUepi@9lnJdY1LFDpdgSgtJUmx0xC3KZVVUrUYFhijdK79QaQ@x2paotWZRCDDqDHyUtLa5AG6JVS7@x@rILpuAimfl4Z5ivXfU593l5JQc/CdXmrcobrYjNsMP4UpOczrtXGy/ZohGUFfV0VA1ecG2kboyHHspZ@1w3UmoZY71OuY5OWlGuId6rUFg5U7Dc/8ktHgOS7tvLgVY31jjSxpWbaM0zLL7hJW@dtHoXO2Jm/hjOCKBQXCGezD6fj3L935/7kDwfxvnqwA3VIHmuRLEWyoKMEK0EokmUYEyarMIwIFyKO/uHWjbr@Bw)

#### Explanation:

```java
int b=a.length,i=0,j=0;                               //Create Variables
for(;i++<b;){for(;j<b;j++){                           //Nested Loop
if(a[j].length()!=b||a[i].charAt(j)!=a[j].charAt(i))  //Is the grid valid?
    return false;                                     //if not, return false
}}
return true;                                     //if it gets this far, return true
```

Comment: Is this work with "The words can be given in any order." rule?

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 93 bytes

```powershell
param($a)"$($a|%{$n++;''+($_|% t*y|sort)}|sort)"-eq"$(0..--$n|%{''+($a|% ch* $_|sort)}|sort)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHPT4MwHMXv/BUNKRYGLJ41JtZRCUn5kXWJelrI1mUHHFhYpgH@dvwWptEZe@hL@j7vHfqq8iRVvZdFMeAdukPtUOUqf7Vx7pgY7s5q8cF1bwlxbbzuLNTMPrq6VI3TT2L68g3I6/nc9/EB8JGEHNrsZwgiv@ChN4x720BwbLzLi1p6iDzQgIDQZJSUB8TxzkijjtIjjxFnxCPRggFBONM8YUHw8g/4kzjHLsA0XGowpBEFWUah0DwVfxoXNM7Aos@Mg8QsTkEynj5dgiKjItYeFSvdSUXGElCxYlOUJhzaDQd1yELtmMXyvZKbRm49hE@l2tYwAF5PlpL1sWjg4Qp2mdzR0KtMHnz8d4Fz85UwjX74BA)

Unrolled:

```powershell
param($a)

$x=$a|%{
    $n++                                # number of words
    $letters = $_|% toCharArray|sort    # sorted letters of the current word $_
    ''+$letters                         # convert the letters to a string
}|sort

$y=0..--$n|%{
    $letters = $a|% chars $_|sort       # sorted letters of all words in the $_ position
    ''+$letters                         # convert the letters to a string
}|sort

Write-Output ("$x"-eq"$y")              # convert both arrays to strings, compare them and return a result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 35 bytes

```
ln)wdr@{Jtp==}ay{"True"}{"False"}IE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f8/J0@zPKXIodqrpMDWtjaxsloppKg0Vam2WsktMacYyPB0/f/fR8FVwVHBhctNwVMByObyVHAGirhwATEQRgIA)

Core calculation is 11 bytes. Most of the cost is in parsing the word square (5 bytes) and outputting true or false rather than 1/0 (19 bytes)

```
ln                   #Split by newlines
)wd                  #Map split by spaces
r@                   #Permutation by words
{
 Jtp==               #If the transpose is the same
}ay                  #Any
{"True"}{"False"}IE  #Print "True" or "False" accordingly
```